# A continuous $\overline{\mathbb{F}^W}$ - adapted process X is $\sigma(W)$ - measureable.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{F}=(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0},\mathbb{P})$ be a filtered probability space satisfying the usual conditions, $W$ an $\mathbb{F}$-Brownian motion and $X$ a continuous $\overline{\mathbb{F}^W}$ - adapted process with $\overline{\mathbb{F}^W}$ being the completed filtration generated by $W$. We equip $C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ with the sigma algebra generated by the projections.

In the script my professor claims that $X:\Omega \rightarrow C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ is $\sigma(W)$ - measureable, but I don't see why this should be true since $X$ is only $\overline{\mathbb{F}^W}$ - and not $\mathbb{F}^W$ - adapted.

Remark: This is used for showing that a strong solution to an SDE is a function of $W$.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Could you please give the link to the script or the relevant excerpt?

Comment: I do not believe that it is in general true, that $X$ is $\mathbb{F}^W$-adapted. However, when speaking of strong solutions I believe that we require some notion of completeness on the relevant filtration, so perhaps it is a typo? Or does he mention anything about the usual conditions or similar?

Comment: Yes, we assumed the usual conditions, I corrected this, sorry.